# ArcGIS API for JavaScript Add Shapefile

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api

I've been looking at the example at https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/portal_addshapefile.html.  I can look at the response.featureCollection in Chrome Developer Tools and see an array of point data, but I don't see anything that tells me what projection the data is in.  Is there some other JavaScript call I can make to convert them to lat/lng points?  I need to read the shapefiles and import the coordinates into our database.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the console, you'll be able to see an array under `object object`. Expand it and you'll see different nodes such as geometry, attributes or spatial reference.